# Bitcoin Cash testnet wallet

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, mobile

Hey guys I've been searching for quite some time... Is there any good, except mycelium, wallet which supports testnet Bitcoin Cash?

Thanks for answers in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: "faucet Bitcoin Cash" What's that? Are you looking for a faucet?

Comment: I'm looking for a wallet that support testnet bitcoin cash currency

Answer (score 1):

[Copay](https://copay.io/) is a mobile wallet which supports Bitcoin Cash testnet.

Desktop wallets based on Bitcoin Core should also support testnet; e.g. [Bitcoin ABC](https://www.bitcoinabc.org/) and [Bitcoin Unlimited](https://www.bitcoinunlimited.info/).

Comment: Copay works. Enable [BCH support](https://blog.bitpay.com/bitcoin-cash-wallet-beta/) then create a wallet for [testnet](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/5534).