# Wallet for Bitcoin Cash testnet

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash

Please, advise wallet which supports testnet Bitcoin Cash. 
I used https://ccoin.cash/#wallet, but they support only https://rest.bitcoin.com/v1.

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/72400/bitcoin-cash-testnet-wallet?rq=1